# Facebook not displaying photos

Tags: facebook, photos

Currently I have some problems with Facebook as all photos of my friends are not loaded!

Screenshot:

[image]

The same error occurs on my Mac with Safari, on Windows with Firefox and on Ubuntu with Chromium! Has anyone run ever into this problem? Any idea what I can do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, however i don't know why this happened to me! (Furthermore it could be coincidence if the Facebook servers start working properly!) Deactivating Ad-Block, restarting Firefox and again activating Ad-Block and it is working now... yet i am confused why.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious things to look for are something blocking the URL of the photos.

I've done a quick check on my profile and they are of the form:

```
http://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/....
```

So do you have a proxy or adblocker that's got "akamai" or another part of that URL in it's block list?